Automate QGIS plugin test on Windows
I'm setting up a GitHub workflow that runs on Windows-latest and allows me to test either if the plugin is being installed or if it's working properly.
The code I'm currently using is:
name: DevelopmentTests

on:  [pull_request]


jobs:
  windows_test:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Install QGIS on Chocolatey
        uses: crazy-max/ghaction-chocolatey@v3
        with:
          args: install qgis-ltr -y --version 3.34.6

      - name: Plugin install
        shell: pwsh
        run: |
          $env:PATH="C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.34.6\bin;$env:PATH"
          $env:QGIS_PLUGIN_IN_CI=1
          python-qgis-ltr.bat -m pip install -r test/requirements-test.txt
          python-qgis-ltr.bat -m pytest test

However, the code above does not test the installation. What changes should I make to test both the plugin and its installation?
